# Alternative to "QMessageBox.Yes" for PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I am trying to port over a script of mine from PyQt5 to PyQt6. I have figured out how to port most of the things thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65728543/14558305), however, I have run into an issue.

I have figured out that PyQt6 uses `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Yes` instead of PyQt5's `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes`.

However, when checking if the user pressed "Yes" after a QMessageBox opens, replacing `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes` with `QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Yes` doesn't work (check the examples below).

---

Examples:

**PyQt5:**

```py
reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
reply.setText("Some random text.")
reply.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)

x = reply.exec_()

if x == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
    print("Hello!")
```

Printing "Hello!" here works normally. `(16384 == 16384)`

**PyQt6:**

```py
reply = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
reply.setText("Some random text.")
reply.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Yes | 
                         QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.No)

x = reply.exec()

if x == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Yes:
    print("Hello!")
```

"Hello!" here doesn't print at all. `(16384 != StandardButtons.yes)`

---

I know I could just do:

```py
x = reply.exec()

if x == 16384:
    print("Hello!")
```

because, after pressing "Yes", the QMessageBox equals to 16384 ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984705/values-of-qmessagebox-yes-qmessagebox-no)), but I'd like to *not* use that approach, and rather use something like the PyQt5 example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is clear and well-written, no need to apologize!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of strange. According to the documentation for [QMessageBox.exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.0/qmessagebox.html#exec):

> When using a QMessageBox with standard buttons, this function returns
> a StandardButton value indicating the standard button that was
> clicked.

You are using standard buttons, so this should return a `QMessageBox.StandardButtons` enum.

It's also worth mentioning that comparing integers with enums was not a problem in PyQt5, because enums were implemented with `enum.IntEnum`. Now, they're implemented with `enum.Enum`. From the [Riverbank Computing website](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download):

> All enums are now implemented as enum.Enum (PyQt5 used enum.IntEnum
> for scoped enums and a custom type for traditional named enums). PyQt5
> allowed an int whenever an enum was expected but PyQt6 requires the
> correct type.

However, for some reason, `QMessageBox.exec` returns an integer (I just tried it with `PyQt6==6.0.0`)!

For now, you can get around this by deliberately constructing an enum object from the returned integer:

```
if QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons(x) == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Yes:
            print("Hello!")
```

And, since you're comparing enums, I would suggest using `is` rather than `==`.

Comment: Or even comparing the result with `int(QStandardButtons.Yes)`?

Comment: @musicamante Nope, the `int` constructor throws an Exception.

Comment: Re PyQt5: Python's native `IntEnum`s weren't used, but a custom type

Comment: That doesn't seem very effective or usable. I'll think I'll ask more information on the PyQt ml, Phil is usually very forthcoming as collaborative.

Answer (score 6):

StandardButtons is not an Attribute/Method I can choose for QMessageBox. Not sure if this was maybe updated in the last 4 months, but for me the code works with **StandardButton** instead of **StandardButtons**.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMessageBox

reply = QMessageBox()
reply.setText("Some random text.")
reply.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes | 
                     QMessageBox.StandardButton.No)

x = reply.exec()

if x == QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes:
    print("Hello!")
```

Comment: The new Enum implementation has created some issues and inconsistencies here and there, especially considering the development status. I believe that correct usage requires checking whenever you're using a *flag* or a *enum*. A Enum (which usually has a *singular* namespace) is for the individual values, while a Flag (normally a *plural*) indicates the - possibly bitwise - result: `QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes` is an *Enum*, `QMessageBox.StandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes)` is a *Flag* just like `QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes|QMessageBox.StandardButton.No` also is.

Answer (score 4):

`QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons` are implemented using [`enum.Flag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag) in PyQt6, while `QDialog.exec()` returns an `int`. Sadly these cannot be directly compared, but you can still use:

```py
if x == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Yes.value:
    print("Hello!")
```

Note that the idiomatic `x == int(Yes)` does not work either.

PyQt5 used a wrapped custom `StandardButtons` class (type in `Yes | No` to see this), NOT an [`enum.IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum) as the other answer is claiming. An `IntEnum` would have been a logical choice however since it specifically allows int comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer might be a little late, but here's what works for me in pyqt6.

```
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Information)

msg.setText('Teste')
msg.setInformativeText("This is additional information")
msg.setWindowTitle("MessageBox demo")
#msg.setDetailedText("The details are as follows:")
msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Yes | QMessageBox.StandardButton.Cancel)
msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.msgbtn)
msg.exec()

def msgbtn(self, i):
    print( "Button pressed is:",i.text() )
```

Comment: This doesn't really help, the OP clearly needs to do a comparison with button roles, and using the button text is a terrible choice especially for buttons that are automatically created by Qt: what if the program is used with a different localization, and the "Yes" button returns "Oui", "Ja", "Sì" or "да"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (from PyQt5 to PyQt6) but coding in this way it's running smooth:

```
if QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self,"Foo","PROTECTION NOT FOUND - Exit",QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Yes):
                print("Exit")
```

I used it as 'critical' or 'question' and even 'information' and it's always running

Comment: This is not very effective, as it only works for the static functions, and behaves almost the same as comparing the return of `exec_()` with a basic `if result:`, while the problem at hand is for message boxes constructed dynamically and the comparison with the standard buttons set, which might be more than one and return different values.

Comment: You are right, the previous answer testing value as QtWidgets.QMessageBox.StandardButtons.No or .Abort or .Yes is the correct way.In my case I have only to inform and no choice left.

Answer (score 0):

This way it also served me very well, mainly because it already translates the text of the button.

```
    msgBox = QMessageBox()
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Icon.Information)
    msgBox.setWindowTitle('Excluir Ponto')
    msgBox.setText('Tem certeza que deseja excluir o ponto {point}?'.format(point = self.dialogCUDP.UI.lineEditPoint.text()))
    btn_delete = msgBox.addButton('Excluir', QMessageBox.ButtonRole.YesRole)
    btn_cancel = msgBox.addButton('Cancelar', QMessageBox.ButtonRole.NoRole)
    msgBox.exec()

    if msgBox.clickedButton() == btn_delete:
        if self._serverOn:
            if self.GM.dfPointsManager.deletePointPMCSV(Priceformat.setFormatStrFloat(self.dialogCUDP.UI.lineEditPoint.text())):
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Excluir Ponto', 'Ponto {point}, excluído com sucesso!'.format(point = self.dialogCUDP.UI.lineEditPoint.text()))
                self.disableFieldCUDPoint()
                self.clearFieldCUDPoint()
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Excluir Ponto', 'Não foi possível excluir o ponto {point}!\nPor favor, tente novamente'.format(point = self.dialogCUDP.UI.lineEditPoint.text()))
                msgBox.close()
        else:
            if self._createnewpointPM.deletePointPMCSV(Priceformat.setFormatStrFloat(self.dialogCUDP.UI.lineEditPoint.text())):
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Excluir Ponto', 'Ponto {point}, excluído com sucesso!'.format(point = self.dialogCUDP.UI.lineEditPoint.text()))
                self.disableFieldCUDPoint()
                self.clearFieldCUDPoint()
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Excluir Ponto', 'Não foi possível excluir o ponto {point}!\nPor favor, tente novamente'.format(point = self.dialogCUDP.UI.lineEditPoint.text()))
                msgBox.close()
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but: 1. this doesn't "translate" the text, it sets a *hardcoded* one (which is conceptually wrong for the same reason explained in my other comment); 2. as already said in my comment to your other answer, the point remains: the issue is with the comparison of button roles; while your solution *may* work, it is just a work around that doesn't really address the problem.